# AWS Redshift create a stored procedure to perform a manual vaccum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

My goal is to create a stored procedure that loops through a select statement that will identify tables requiring a vacuum. I will call it from Lambda if I can get it to work. These are my ideas and code so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vac_an (rs_out INOUT refcursor)
AS $$
BEGIN
   OPEN rs_out FOR SELECT 'VACUUM FULL ' + "schema" + '.' + "table" + ';' AS command
FROM svv_table_info
WHERE (unsorted > 5 OR empty > 5)
      AND size < 716800;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is a start. It compiles, but it would not execute the actual command that the cursor builds, which is:

> `VACUUM FULL SCHEMA.TABLE;`

I guess I could call it with this:

```
CALL sample_cursor_test ();
```

My second line of thinking was something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE vac_an()
AS $$
DECLARE
tlist RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR tlist IN EXECUTE 'SELECT 'VACUUM FULL ' + "schema" + '.' + "table" + ';' AS command FROM svv_table_info WHERE (unsorted > 5 OR empty > 5) AND size < 716800;'
LOOP
EXECUTE tlist;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However that gives me :

```
ERROR: missing "LOOP" at end of SQL expression
  Where: compile of PL/pgSQL function "vac_an" near line 4
```

I feel like the code is almost there I just need to loop through this cursor:

```
SELECT 'VACUUM FULL ' + "schema" + '.' + "table" + ';' AS command
FROM svv_table_info
WHERE (unsorted > 5 OR empty > 5)
      AND size < 716800;
```

And execute the output line by line.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `VACUUM` from within a transaction, which means you cannot call `VACUUM` from within a procedure, since a procedure is inherently a transaction.

Comment: Thanks Max. Are you sure though? Apparently this is meant to work in Postgresql and they are very similar databases  ------ > CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE analyze_schema(schema_Name VARCHAR DEFAULT 'public') 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
DECLARE
  tab RECORD;
BEGIN
  for tab in (select tablename 
                FROM pg_tables t
                WHERE schemaname = schema_Name
                order by 1)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'ANALYZE %.%', schema_Name, tab.tablename;
   EXECUTE 'ANALYZE '||quote_ident(schema_Name)||'.'||quote_ident(tab.tablename);
  end loop;
end
$$;

Comment: This works in postgresql: ---> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vacuum_schema(schema_Name VARCHAR DEFAULT 'public') 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
DECLARE
  tab RECORD;
BEGIN
  for tab in (select tablename from pg_tables 
        where schemaname = schema_name)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'VACUUM %.%', schema_Name, tab.tablename;
    EXECUTE 'VACUUM '||quote_ident(schema_Name)||'.'||quote_ident(tab.tablename);
  end loop;
end
$$;

CALL vacuum_schema('schema_name');

Comment: Anyone know why it does no work in redshift?

Comment: Well I guess that settles that:  CALL vacuum_schema('bob')
Error report -
ERROR: VACUUM cannot be executed from a function or procedure
  Where: SQL statement "VACUUM bob.test"
PL/pgSQL function "vacuum_schema" line 8 at execute statement

Comment: `VACUUM` in Redshift is very different in its implementation and operation than on Postgres.  In Redshift, the changes it induces cannot be handled by MVCC, and so it cannot be part of a transaction.